System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'FreeImage' or one of its dependencies
I have a .net8 web application where I'm using the FreeImage-dotnet-core 4.3.6 package. Locally it seemed to be working fine, but after deploying the app in azure, this error appears:

System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'FreeImage'
or one of its dependencies.

What causes this error and how can I fix it? Both systems are running Windows.
